# apache ab rool return unknown error (10108) apr_sockaddr_info_get

Tags: apache, windows-7-x64, apachebench

I'm using Apache ab for testing.

But when I run the tool like this:

```
ab -n10 'http://localhost'`
```

it returns:

```
This is ApacheBench, Version 2.0.40-dev <$Revision: 1.121.2.4 $> apache-2.0
Copyright (c) 1996 Adam Twiss, Zeus Technology Ltd, http://www.zeustech.net/
Copyright (c) 1998-2002 The Apache Software Foundation, http://www.apache.org/

Benchmarking 'http: (be patient)...apr_sockaddr_info_get() for 'http:: Unknown e
rror (10108)
```

Can anyone help me to solve this problem?

I'm using windows 7. I've already installed apache and it successfully returns test page using:

```
http://localhost
```

Thanks.

Comment: I can add that I have exactly the same error on some domains and trying to test from dedicated Ubuntu server.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem and i just used the command like that `ab -n 100 http://localhost:8080/` directly without quotes and make sure that your httpd.conf file contains the

```
#ServerName localhost
```

it's located in

> ..\Apache2.2\conf\